# Jar cron job not running (runs manually)

Tags: java, jar, amazon-ec2, cron

First time using cron jobs and im relatively new with linux and i just cant seem to get it to work, it works fine if i just manually run it in command line but not as a cron job.

I set it up like this:

- contrab -e
- insert mode
- */3  *  *  *  * root  (cd /home/ec2-user/; java -jar feedPuller-1.jar) (every 3 minutes just to test)
- Save and quit
- It says it has created a new cron job tab

Now when i do crontab -l the job is there, and when i simple do the command "cd /home/ec2-user/; java -jar feedPuller-1.jar" it runs perfectly and finally when i check the cron log in /var/log/ it has

```
Oct 10 00:30:34 ip-172-31-29-33 crontab[28934]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
Oct 10 00:33:25 ip-172-31-29-33 crontab[28934]: (root) REPLACE (root)
Oct 10 00:33:25 ip-172-31-29-33 crontab[28934]: (root) END EDIT (root)
Oct 10 00:33:48 ip-172-31-29-33 crontab[28937]: (root) LIST (root)
Oct 10 00:34:01 ip-172-31-29-33 crond[28932]: (root) BAD FILE MODE (/etc/cron.d/0hourly)
Oct 10 00:34:01 ip-172-31-29-33 crond[28932]: (root) BAD FILE MODE (/etc/cron.d/update-motd)
Oct 10 00:36:01 ip-172-31-29-33 CROND[28942]: (root) CMD (root  (cd /home/ec2-user/; java -jar     feedPuller-1.jar))
Oct 10 00:39:01 ip-172-31-29-33 CROND[28949]: (root) CMD (root  (cd /home/ec2-user/; java -jar feedPuller-1.jar))
Oct 10 00:42:01 ip-172-31-29-33 CROND[29041]: (root) CMD (root  (cd /home/ec2-user/; java -jar feedPuller-1.jar))
```

So that means it is running right? But when i check the local database (that the jar should be writing to) nothing is being written (if i run the jar with cd /home/ec2-user/; java -jar feedPuller-1.jar it writes to the database no problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies, my lack of understanding of cron jobs and linux in general was causing me to make a basic error.

In my cron tab ive changed it to

```
*/30  *  *  *  * java -jar /home/ec2-user/feedPuller-1.jar
```

and everything is working fine